# URL: response.redirect, VS2012 or IIS?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-7, response.redirect

I have a website in aspx with c # and am having trouble making the transition between pages. I tulizando the following code;
response.redirect ("page.aspx"), where the url should be www.mysite.com.br / sipp / page.aspx, but the url is being passed www.mysite.com.br/sipp/ 2fsipp% 2f% / page.aspx. causing the page not found.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the URL being passed to Response.Redirect as follows:

```
Response.Redirect( Server.URL.Encode("myUrl"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntaxe is

```
Response.Redirect([url]);
```

where the [url] is the path to your required page.

In your case you should try :

```
Response.Redirec("/fsipp/page.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code.

```
Response.Redirec("/sipp/page.aspx");
```

you can also try with another way: Server.Transfer()

```
Server.Transfer("/sipp/page.aspx");
```

If you are using Server.Transfer() then you can directly access the values, controls and properties of the previous page which you can’t do with Response.Redirect().

http://arplis.com/difference-between-server-transfer-and-response-redirect/

Comment: I've tried both ways and it did not work, the project name is added to the url.

Server.Transfer gives problem with AJAX.